# PQXX connection string: How to avoid hardcode the string connection?

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, database-connection, libpqxx

Currently I am working on a project which set up proper connections to the database via md5 connection to PostgreSQL. I am using the pqxx library and c++ obviously.

I am looking and reading about the kind of connections PostgreSQL can handle, for example:

1. Trust authentication
2. Password authentication (md5)
3. GSSAPI authentication

and so on.

I am using a Inversion of Control design to connect to the database, every class I have for connecting to different database I am managing are establishing the connection when the object is constructed. Inside the constructor the string is hard-coded, meaning, I have the ip, port, user and password declared there, I am looking a kind of way to connect to the database without declaring the string in the code due to security problems that can/could happen.

I already checked PostgreSQL documentation: [authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html)

And also checked the pg_crypto file and options if there was any option to use it for my purpose.

Anyone has any experience with this from the server side using pqxx/c++?

Thank you so much in advance.